# Authorisation and role check in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, x509certificate

I have a spring boot application where I have several REST APIs. Now I want to do a authorisation check for all the requests. This involves each request using a x509 client certificate and then some business logic for authorisation purpose, something similar to role checking. 
what is the best place to do this i.e. should this check be done in DispatcherServlet - doDispatch method? Doing the same check for each request in Controller doesn't make much of a sense. 
Can someone suggest where to put these kind of checks in a spring boot application ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. Java config or xml config.

I recommend java config. Create a config class and configure like this

For java config it would look something like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {
        authenticationMgr.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("jduser").password("jdu@123").authorities("ROLE_USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("jdadmin").password("jda@123").authorities("ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/homePage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/userPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/adminPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homePage")
                .failureUrl("/loginPage?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")                
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage?logout"); 

    }
}
```